# JaCoCo doesn't work with Robolectric tests

Tags: android, code-coverage, robolectric, jacoco

I wanted to generate code coverage reports on my JUnit tests in my android project so I added the JaCoCo gradle plugin. This is my project level `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects { prj ->
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    jacoco {
        toolVersion '0.7.6.201602180812'
    }

    task jacocoReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {
        group = 'Reporting'
        description = 'Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests.'

        reports {
            xml {
                enabled = true
                destination "${prj.buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.xml"
            }
            html {
                enabled = true
                destination "${prj.buildDir}/reports/jacoco"
            }
        }

        classDirectories = fileTree(
                dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/debug',
                excludes: [
                        '**/R*.class',
                        '**/BuildConfig*',
                        '**/*$$*'
                ]
        )

        sourceDirectories = files('src/main/java')
        executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')

        doFirst {
            files('build/intermediates/classes/debug').getFiles().each { file ->
                if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                    file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion '0.7.6.201602180812'
}

task jacocoFullReport(type: JacocoReport, group: 'Coverage reports') {
    group = 'Reporting'
    description = 'Generates an aggregate report from all subprojects'

    //noinspection GrUnresolvedAccess
    dependsOn(subprojects.jacocoReport)

    additionalSourceDirs = project.files(subprojects.jacocoReport.sourceDirectories)
    sourceDirectories = project.files(subprojects.jacocoReport.sourceDirectories)
    classDirectories = project.files(subprojects.jacocoReport.classDirectories)
    executionData = project.files(subprojects.jacocoReport.executionData)

    reports {
        xml {
            enabled = true
            destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/full/jacoco.xml"
        }
        html {
            enabled = true
            destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/full"
        }
    }

    doFirst {
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll { it.exists() })
    }
}
```

It works great by running `./gradlew jacocoFullReport`. But unfortunately coverage is not reported for the tests that are run with the `RobolectricTestRunner` (instructions that are obviously called in the tests are not reported as covered). Tests with no `@RunWith` annotation or run with `MockitoJUnitTestRunner` report coverage just fine.

Any help would be appreciated to fix this problem.

**Update 1:** I noticed that I should be using the `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`. But it didn't help.

Comment: I want to say that this is definitely possible, but I've no idea how to fix it. I managed to get code coverage working for Robolectric at an old job, but that was a year ago and I no longer have access to that code anymore. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: `testCoverageEnabled` in later versions of gradle uses Jacoco, you dont need to apply plugin. Try without the plugin.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I believe setting testCoverageEnabled to true only works with android instrumentation tests, which require a connected device. And that's what I try to avoid by using Robolectric.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is known issue with the possible workaround - https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/288

Or downgrade **jacoco** version to `0.7.1.201405082137`

**UPDATE**

The workaround is not needed anymore. You must use **gradle** version `2.13` and **jacoco** version `0.7.6.201602180812`.

Update root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.6.201602180812'
    }
}

task wrapper( type: Wrapper ) {
  gradleVersion = '2.13'
}
```

Run `./gradlew wrapper`

Update project `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
      jacoco {
        includeNoLocationClasses = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the workaround doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: In this case if it is not principal for you then lower version of jacoco to `0.7.1.201405082137`. It still might be the problem if you use jenkins latest jacoco plugin. Also downgrade version of it to something `1.8`

Comment: Downgrading jacoco did the trick. I use travis-ci and there is no problem with it.

Comment: In the update section, doing `classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.6.201602180812'` should not be required as that's what `apply plugin` does anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you remove it than you will use default jacoco plugin and I'm not sure if it is latest. Did you try this?

Comment: Get the following error after following these step - Error:No such property: includeNoLocationClasses for class: org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension_Decorated

Comment: Which version of havoc do you use?

Comment: I have it working on Jacoco: toolVersion = "0.7.7.201606060606", what changed for me was just adding the includeNoLocationClasses = true

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is a bit dated.  Here is a similar fix we just implemented.  In the module (i.e. app) build.gradle add:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}
```

This does require JaCoCo 7.6+, but you are likely using it already.

Notes for Studio:

1. This only fixes the CLI.  If you run coverage from Studio using JaCoCo, the Robolectric coverage is still not reported.  The default IntelliJ Coverage Runner seems to work fine.
2. The test were crashing intermittently in Studio unless I added -noverify to the Android JUnit -> VM Options

Comment: This seems to be the most accurate answer to date.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue but now it is resolved for me by following this link,

issue link: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2230

Solution for this problem is mentioned here:

https://github.com/dampcake/Robolectric-JaCoCo-Sample/commit/f9884b96ba5e456cddb3d4d2df277065bb26f1d3

Comment: Eugen Martynov suggested the same thing. But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I changed the jacoco plugin version and added includenolocationclasses property. Here is the working jacoco.gradle file (I am using gradle wrapper 2.14.1):

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
}

android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    // Grab all build types and product flavors
    def buildTypes = android.buildTypes.collect { type -> type.name }
    def productFlavors = android.productFlavors.collect { flavor -> flavor.name }
    println(buildTypes)
    println(productFlavors)
    // When no product flavors defined, use empty
    if (!productFlavors) productFlavors.add('')

    productFlavors.each { productFlavorName ->
        buildTypes.each { buildTypeName ->
            def sourceName, sourcePath
            if (!productFlavorName) {
                sourceName = sourcePath = "${buildTypeName}"
            } else {
                sourceName = "${productFlavorName}${buildTypeName.capitalize()}"
                sourcePath = "${productFlavorName}/${buildTypeName}"
            }
            def testTaskName = "test${sourceName.capitalize()}UnitTest"
            println("SourceName:${sourceName}")
            println("SourcePath:${sourcePath}")
            println("testTaskName:${testTaskName}")
            // Create coverage task of form 'testFlavorTypeCoverage' depending on 'testFlavorTypeUnitTest'
            task "${testTaskName}Coverage" (type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
                group = "Reporting"
                description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the ${sourceName.capitalize()} build."

                classDirectories = fileTree(
                        dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${sourcePath}",
                        excludes: ['**/R.class',
                                   '**/R$*.class',
                                   '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                                   '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                                   '**/BuildConfig.*',
                                   '**/Manifest*.*']
                )

                def coverageSourceDirs = [
                        "src/main/java",
                        "src/$productFlavorName/java",
                        "src/$buildTypeName/java"
                ]
                additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
                sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
                executionData = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")
                println("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")
                reports {
                    xml.enabled = true
                    html.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old issue, but for those who are still facing, it is worth mentioning that if you are setting up JaCoCo + Robolectric + Espresso - you will indeed be using `includeNoLocationClasses`, but still will see this error with Java9+ and probably end up here. Add the below snippet to your module **build.gradle** file

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
  jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning the jacoco.excludes statement. Without that the unit tests in my project crashed.

Answer (score -1):

change coverage runner to jacoco in android studio
1- select app(root of the project)
2 click on menu (run --> Edit configurations --> code coverage --> choose JaCoCo).

[image: the screenshot is below]